# HTML5 Validation and jQuery POST

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have a form and I use html5 validation such as `required="required"` in my form controls and trying to submit it using jQuery `.post` function. I do it this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '.save-and-new', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = '/Weight/Manage';
  var data = $('#manageWeight-form').serialize();
  var jqxhr = $.post(url, data, function (d) {
     alert("success");
  });
});
```

The problem is, when I do this the html5 validation is not triggered. I'm assuming it is because of the `preventDefault()` function but I need it because I want the form which is by the way inside a modal, to stay on the same page.
How can I make use of html5 validation and submit the form using jquery post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do HTML-5 validation using form submit method instead of click on submit button

```
$('#manageWeight-form').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = '/Weight/Manage';
  var data = $('#manageWeight-form').serialize();
  var jqxhr = $.post(url, data, function (d) {
     alert("success");
  });
  return false;
});
```

#### See This

```js
$('#manageWeight-form').submit(function (e,btn_id) {
  
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).data('submitted-by'));
  var url = '/Weight/Manage';
  var data = $('#manageWeight-form').serialize();
  var jqxhr = $.post(url, data, function (d) {
     alert("success");
  });
  return false;
});

$('#manageWeight-form input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
  
  $('#manageWeight-form').data('submitted-by',$(this).attr('id'));
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="manageWeight-form">
  <input name="aaa" required />
  <input name="bbb" required />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit 1" id="AAA"/>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit 2" id="BBBB"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: yeah you're right. That works but what Im doing is I have 2 submit buttons and I need to know which button is clicked.

Comment: how can I know which button triggered the submit event

Comment: Can you put your HTML code snippet in your question so I can give accurate answer :)

Comment: I have solved your question also... you can set data-submitted-by attribute in your form tag.